# Why isn't self automatically declared as unowned in blocks?

Tags: swift, memory-management, closures, automatic-ref-counting

Up till now, I've been naïvely using Swift without really caring about the memory management. But I'm implementing a capture list, and I guess it sort of makes sense.

My question is - why wouldn't `self` be automatically made unowned to avoid retain cycles? Is there a situation in which you'd explicitly need `self` to be owned that couldn't be resolved by saving some of its data elsewhere?

Comment: `self` isn't always the owner of the block.  And the owner of the block doesn't necessarily know who `self` is.  Apple would either have to add in some precompiler steps to make it unowned by default if unspecified, or we'd have to add a little bit of runtime overhead to check whether or not a specific variable matches the memory location of the object that passed the block...

Comment: You may *want* to retain self until some asynchronously dispatched code is executed.  And a  retain cycle is not necessarily bad, only if it is not broken eventually. The compiler cannot guess your intention.

Answer (score 2):

Give you a simple example

This is a class that I need to use self,not `unowned self`

If I use `self` here

```
class Test{

func log(){
    println("log");
}
func FunctionHaveBlock(){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
        () -> Void in

        sleep(4)
        self.log()
    })
}
deinit{
    println("Deinit")
}
}
```

Then call

```
  var test:Test? = Test()
    test!.FunctionHaveBlock();
    test = nil;
```

The code will executed well,after 4 seconds,it will log

> log
>   Deinit

**But if I changed to `unowned self`,**

```
class Test{

func log(){
    println("log");
}
func FunctionHaveBlock(){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
        [unowned self]
        () -> Void in

        sleep(4)
        self.log()
    })
}
deinit{
    println("Deinit")
}
```

}

Then call

```
   var test:Test? = Test()
    test!.FunctionHaveBlock();
    test = nil;
```

It will log

> Deinit

then After 4 seconds,the app crashed.Because,the object is dealloced.

**So,if you need to retain the object,you do not use `unowned self`**